# What kinds of love do individual Greek gods represent?

Tags: greek, aphrodite, concepts, love

The Greeks had four concepts for love: *éros* ([ἔρος](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3De)%2Fros1)), *storgē* ([στοργή](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dstorgh%2F)), *philía* ([φιλία](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dfili%2Fa)) and *agápe* ([ἀγάπη](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0058%3Aentry%3Da)ga%2Fph)). Eros being passionate love or romantic love. Storge means love between good friends and family. Philia is translated as friendship. And agape is an unconditional love for all you meet, translated as affection, meaning 'greet with affection.'

The only obvious connection is the god Eros paired with the concept of eros. Eros would make mortals and gods fall in love by shooting them with his gold arrows. He could also turn their heart away from love by shooting them with lead arrows (Daphne and Apollo).

I have a hard time placing Aphrodite. My first thought was that agape somehow came from Aphrodite. But after looking at translations and definitions of the four, I would say she most fits the concept of eros.

What concepts do other Greek gods and goddess represent?

Comment: For Aphrodite, *éros*, no question.  For *philía*, only Artemis comes to mind because she is known for roaming the wilderness with her companions, where fondness is implied. [*Agápe*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agape#Early_Uses) does not seem to apply to any god or goddess in the Greek pantheon, and is used mainly in the New Testament.  *Storgē* could be applied to Zeus in relation to Athena, but perhaps no other.  (I may do a formal answer, but it would require running down source material to support--thought you'd appreciate a quickie answer in the meantime:)

Comment: On reflection, there is an earlier use of agape http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Da)ga%2Fph related to husband and wife. But Hera is the goddess of marriage, and hers is one of strife (see Hesiod on choosing the wrong life-partner;) Nevertheless, Hera is the one instance of a Greek god showing agape in the Christian sense, when she forgives Hercules on his pyre in the Ovid, which is published ~8 years after the given date for birth of Jesus, and a couple decades before the crucifixion.

Comment: https://mrgntmthy.wordpress.com/2013/02/28/agape-goddess-of-divine-love/
Just came across this link & thought it might be usefull to share in this subject _/\_